# Python index starts at 0. Any possibility to set index value as 1 for any terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing

I am porting the Matlab code to Python. In Matlab, indices start at 1, but in python, they start at 0. Is there any way to set the first index as 1 through a command line flag?

It will be very useful for programming during index iteration.

Comment: Thank you ...ok @j1-lee. Let see any other helps

Comment: j1-lee is correct. You'd have to change large amounts of the Python codebase to do so, introducing who knows how many bugs in the process. Python has been designed over the last 30+ years around 0-based indexing. There's no way around it. You'll just have to convert manually.

Comment: You might be able to do this by overriding the `__getitem__()` method of the built-in type `list`, but that would be a lot of work for something so simple. I'd recommend porting your code and writing a regex to rewrite the list indices instead.

Comment: You might also be able to subclass `list` and add wrap all your lists in a new type

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no way to do this. Python is a 0-indexed language. Guido Van Rossum (Python creator) explained his reasons behind selecting 0-indexing over 1-indexing in this blog post:

http://python-history.blogspot.com/2013/10/why-python-uses-0-based-indexing.html

Comment: This answer is wrong. There are two other answers which explain how to actually do this.

Comment: @MichaelM.- sorry, but i don't understand... which answers in SO explain how to make Python into a 1-indexed language??? I'm pretty sure it is impossible

Comment: ... just sub-classing List is not going to cover all corner cases of a matlab code base...

Answer (score 1):

As far as Python is concerned, there cannot be changes in the Indexing part. It always starts with 0 (Zero) only and progresses onwards.
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, starting from 0 is easier for all computer-related tasks - it is just that mathematical notation, as inherited by matlab starts at 1.

For compatibility and ease-to-port code, I think you could write some special cased classes that would modify the indexes in access-time, so that one won't have to worry about changing indexes at a first porting-pass (but I'd drop those and revert to 0-indexed structures in a second pass).

You would have to use those special-purposed data structures instead of the built-in lists and tuples - and, when moving to n-dimensional arrays, in numpy code, it might become simply to hard to be worth it to have the "+1" data structures working, as there are lots of corner cases with multi-dimensional indexes.

For plain lists though, you can have a displaced list by just re-writting the `__getitem__`, `__setitem__` and `__delitem__` methods.

```
class MatList(list):
 
   def __getitem__(self, index):
       return super().__getitem__(index - 1)
   def __setitem__(self, index, value):
       return super().__setitem__(index - 1, value)
   def __delitem__(self, index):
       return super().__delitem__(index - 1)
```

Add more methods as needed (`.index` for example, or `.pop`)

Comment: Thank you , tried the same method, it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Ah, after some research I found the solution. This is doable, but I don't recommend it. You can subclass `list` and then replace `list` with your new wrapper. Like this:

```
class ListWrapper(list):
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return super().__getitem__(index-1)


list = ListWrapper

lst = ListWrapper([1, 2, 3])
print(lst[2])  # => 2
```

This is only part of the solution though. You'll need to add more methods to change the index as you use them. For example, you'll need to make wrappers for `__setitem__()` and `__delitem__()`.

Comment: Thanks, it helps in my code. But the info is [0] index changed to the last element in the list :) . Anyhow thank you !

Answer (score -2):

i'm not aware of whether you can change that by default.
But you can specify the starting and ending indexes for loops with range, enumerate, etc.
e.g.

```
for i in range(1, end + 1):
```

Comment: That's not at all what the question is asking. `range()` is still 0-based.

Comment: Hi zccafa3 thank you for answering, but I am looking for different

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).